# if i update a phone fields in lead then create a task

Tags: apex, trigger

**Trigger :**

```
 trigger CreateTaskOnLead on Lead (after insert,after update) {
       List<Task> lstTask = new List<Task>();
        list<lead> lea=trigger.new;{
               for(Lead objLead: lea) {
                   if((objLead.phone != trigger.oldMap.get(objLead.id).phone){
                     task objTask = new Task(); 
                     objTask.OwnerId = objLead.OwnerId;
                     objTask.Subject = 'Call';
                     objTask.Priority = 'Normal';
                     objTask.Status = 'Not Started';
                     objTask.Description = objLead.Description;
                     objTask.WhoID = objLead.id;
                     lstTask.add(objTask);   
                   }
                }
                if(!lstTask.IsEmpty())
                    insert lstTask;
               }        
          }
```

Comment: If you're new to Salesforce, you might want to simply use Process Builder, which you can learn about in [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder). Using the Process Builder, you can define your criteria and build an action for creating the task, all without writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written trigger on after update that is correct but at Line number 4 in your code you are checking for ***trigger.isInsert***, that is incorrect.

**Also I see in your code you are not looking if actually the Phone number is changed on the record or not.**

Your trigger should look like:

```
List<Task> lstTask = new List<Task>();
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate ) {
    for(Lead objLead: Trigger.new) {
        Lead oldLead = trigger.oldMap.get( objLead.Id );

        if( objLead.Phone != oldLead.Phone ){
            Task objTask = new Task(); 
            objTask.OwnerId = objLead.OwnerId;
            objTask.Subject = 'Call';
            objTask.Priority = 'Normal';
            objTask.Status = 'Not Started';
            objTask.Description = objLead.Description;
            objTask.WhoID = objLead.id;
            lstTask.add(objTask);   
        }
    }
    if(!lstTask.IsEmpty())
        insert lstTask;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thatherahere the trigger is working fine. Thanks for given me quick response.thank you so much sir.

Comment: Glad to hear this. Please mark this question as resolved. 
Also look into the suggestion from @sfdcfox :)